# 8-bit AVR: single instruction to put a value of 1, ~1(-2/0xfe) or 4 into one of the registers not eligible for immediate operands (r0...r15)?

Tags: loops, assembly, avr

With 8-bit AVR, immediate operands can be used with r16 to r32, including `ldi r16, 4`.

I want to control loops to run 4 and 8 times, respectively, and can't afford one more instruction for both for compatibility reasons, let alone a push/pop pair.

Is there a way to get a value of 1 or -2 (~1) into r0 with a single single-word instruction?
0 is easy enough: `clr r0`. With carry set, `sbc r0, r0` gets -1.

Failing that, what about 4, 8, 16 to 31, 224 to 239?

Please include suggestions depending on *carry flag set*.

Comment: I think there is no such way in single instruction.

Comment: To loop 8 times you could load -1 and shift it instead of incrementing and stop when it becomes zero. There might be more solutions if you don't just focus on loading a constant. As a hack, you might have a SFR that happens to contain a value you want. You could load that via `IN`.

Comment: @Jester `load -1 and shift it instead of incrementing` true, but [right now](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78214205/2) I'm shifting a 0x01 left until there is a carry - filling that same register with quotient bits, so comparing to 0 isn't useful.

Comment: (While a solution would be great to know, it would be [the X solution](//en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to the __Y problem__ at hand: *controlling both an outer loop and an inner one with 8 iterations per iteration of the outer loop in fewest AVR instructions possible*. When the code in the outer loop following a `subi counters, 2  brhc innerTop` preserves the carry flag, use a `brcc outerTop` for up to 16 iterations of the outer loop and just 4 instructions all told - you can use `ldi` with any register you can manipulate with `subi`, possibly using one register less in the process.)